# How to extract latitude and longitude in a web

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, hyperlink

I have extract some infos in https://www.peakbagger.com/list.aspx?lid=5651 under the first column https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10882

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10882'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

a= soup.select("td")
a
```

would want to only retrieve the latitude and longitude which is 35.360638, 138.727347 from the output I get.

It is in

```
E<br/>35.360638, 138.727347
```

And also, is there a better way to retrieve all the latitude and longitude from the links of /www.peakbagger.com/list.aspx?lid=5651 other than doing one by one?

Thanks

Comment: `... not sure how to...` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: the string *138.727347* cant be found in https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10882/

Comment: @balderman try to click on the link again, I think I put a slash at the end, maybe. Try this: https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brutus mentioned, it is very specific and if you wont to use `etree` this could be an alternativ.

- `find()` `<td>` with the string `Latitude/Longitude (WGS84)`
- `findNext()` its next `<td>`
- grab its contents
- replace the , and split it by the whitespace
- by slicing the result to the first two elements you will get the list with  lat and long.

.

```
data = soup.find('td', string='Latitude/Longitude (WGS84)')\
            .findNext('td')\
            .contents[2]\
            .replace(',','')\
            .split()[:2]

data
```

#### EDIT

You have a list of urls and loop over it - To be considerate of the website and not to be banned, run over the pages with some delay (`time.sleep()`).

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urls = ['https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10882',
 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10866',
 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10840',
 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10868',
 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10832']

data = {}

for url in urls:
    
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    

    ll= soup.find('td', string='Latitude/Longitude (WGS84)')\
                .findNext('td')\
                .contents[2]\
                .replace(',','')\
                .split()[:2]
    
    data[soup.select_one('h1').get_text()]={
        'url':url,
        'lat':ll[0],
        'long':ll[1]
    }
 
    time.sleep(3)

data
```

#### Output

```
{'Fuji-san, Japan': {'url': 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10882',
  'lat': '35.360638',
  'long': '138.727347'},
 'Kita-dake, Japan': {'url': 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10866',
  'lat': '35.674537',
  'long': '138.238833'},
 'Hotaka-dake, Japan': {'url': 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10840',
  'lat': '36.289203',
  'long': '137.647986'},
 'Aino-dake, Japan': {'url': 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10868',
  'lat': '35.646037',
  'long': '138.228292'},
 'Yariga-take, Japan': {'url': 'https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10832',
  'lat': '36.34198',
  'long': '137.647625'}}
```

Comment: ok, just wonder is how to get all the Latitude & Longitude from all the links in  https://www.peakbagger.com/list.aspx?lid=5651, meaning all at once

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very specific to your problem. The issue here is with the br tags occurring inside td tags. The etree module (part of lxml) allows you to access text following a tag (a.k.a. its *tail*). This code will print the values you've shown as being your desired output.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get('https://www.peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=10882')
    r.raise_for_status()
    tree = etree.HTML(r.text)
    print(' '.join(tree.xpath('//table[@class="gray"][1]/*//br')[1].tail.split()[:2]))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Is it possible to do it all at once to get the long/lang for all the links in  https://www.peakbagger.com/list.aspx?lid=5651

Comment: @Annie yes, it is possible to do it all at once to get the long/lang for all the links using scrapy . just create a new post.